# Handling OUT parameter with Stored Procedure Outbound Channel Adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in my project. I have a weird scenario that needs to be handled. When I connected to DB2 databse, My stored procedure will not return any result. So, I have used `int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter` and `int:publish-subscribe-channel` to execute the stored procedure and continue the flow of execution.

Now, the same stored procedure in Oracle database returns some result. So using `int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter` for executing the Oracle stored procedure is causing the issue as it is expecting an extra parameter i.e `OUT` to be defined.

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA
```

Is there any way to define `OUT` parameter for `int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter` so that the Oracle stored procedure gets executed without any issue.

P.S. I am least bothered if the `int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter` doesn't return anything, but the stored procedure should be executed with the `OUT` parameter succesfully.

Is there any way to manage such situation?

> UPDATE

Following is my Oracle stored procedure:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA (

         P_USERID           char,
         P_BUSINESSAREA     char,
         P_SELECTEDIND      char,
         P_DEFAULTIND       char,
         P_LEGACYSYSTEM     char,
         P_LEGACYLOGIN      char,
         P_LEGACYPASSWORD   char,
         P_OTHERLOGIN       char,
         P_OTHERPASSWORD    char,
         P_ADDSECURLOGIN    char,
         P_ADDSECURPASSWORD char,
         P_LASTUPDATEUSERID char,
         P_LASTUPDATE       char, cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

AS
BEGIN

OPEN cur FOR SELECT * from USERBUSINESSAREA
where (USERID       =  P_USERID
AND      BUSINESSAREA   =  P_BUSINESSAREA);

INSERT 
INTO    USERBUSINESSAREA    
        (
            USERID,
            BUSINESSAREA,
            SELECTEDIND,
            DEFAULTIND,
            LEGACYSYSTEM,
            LEGACYLOGIN,
            LEGACYPASSWORD,
            OTHERLOGIN,
            OTHERPASSWORD,
            ADDSECURLOGIN,
            ADDSECURPASSWORD,
            LASTUPDATEUSERID,
            LASTUPDATE
        )

VALUES  ( P_USERID,
          P_BUSINESSAREA,
          P_SELECTEDIND,
          P_DEFAULTIND,
          P_LEGACYSYSTEM,
          P_LEGACYLOGIN,
          P_LEGACYPASSWORD,
          P_OTHERLOGIN,
          P_OTHERPASSWORD,
          P_ADDSECURLOGIN,
          P_ADDSECURPASSWORD,
          P_LASTUPDATEUSERID,
          P_LASTUPDATE);

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like it described in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#stored-procedure-outbound-channel-adapter):

```
<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="YOUR_OUT_PARAM" direction="OUT"/>
```

**UPDATE**

For Oracle you have to declare `ignore-column-meta-data="true"` and define all the parameters manually using that `<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition>`.

If your `OUT` param is `SYS_REFCURSOR`, the `sql-parameter-definition` must be like:

```
<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="CUR" direction="OUT" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).CURSOR}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still getting the same error after configuring the `OUT` parameter. FYI, my `OUT` parameter is cursor that returns a `ResultSet` in case of Oracle. However the `ResultSet` won't be returned in case of DB2. Any ideas now?

Comment: So, you need two separate adapters definitions - for Oracle and for DB2. Consider to sever them via `profile`.

Comment: To define the parameter properly we need to know the signature of your Oracle procedure. Maybe it is a `function` and it really does `return`...

Comment: I have added my Oracle stored procedure to the question. Please take a look.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: I am now getting the exception during deployment `Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "jdbc" for element "jdbc:returning-resultset" is not bound.`

Comment: Will `jdbc:returning-resultset` work with `int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter`? That might be the issue I guess, but not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: That is just an XML Namespace prefix. Of course you have to use defined in your config for particular schema location.

Comment: I got your point. Now I am getting `Invalid content was found starting with element 'int-jdbc:returning-resultset'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc":parameter, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc":request-handler-advice-chain}' is expected.`

Comment: OK. Try without `returning-resultset`. That is really not available on the `stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter`. Sorry.

Comment: Super!! It worked with Oracle. Will it work with DB2? Let me test now.. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with DB2. I'm afraid you have to declare separate `stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter` and distinguish them via `profile`. I told you about that already a couple comments above.

Comment: Whops! It's not working with DB2. Getting the error `[SQL0440] Routine ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA in *N not found with specified parameters.`. The reason could be  the extra OUT parameter we have added for Oracle type. Can we add the this OUT parameter based on driver type, may be by using an expression. Is there any way?

Comment: See my comment about `profile`. I'm already tired with your inattentiveness and a wish that I should do all the work for you. Sorry, I give up. I have a lot of my own work to do. No help for you from my side any more...

Comment: Thanks much!! I was just curious to know if it can be managed  by just using an expression. Any way, I will go with `profile` . Please forgive me if I irritated you. Thanks :)